# sequelizer migration script throwing errorUnhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table

Tags: node.js, orm, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have written sequelizer migration javascript to make changes in the existing column in a table , but when I am running the command `sequelizer db:migrate`
, its giving the error

`== 20170212050240-alter_col_tag_subject: migrating =======`
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: subject_tags`
`== 20170212050240-alter_col_tag_subject: migrated (0.241s)`

here is the code for the migration file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return [
                queryInterface.changeColumn(
                  'subject_tags',
                  'tag',
                    {
                       type: Sequelize.STRING,
                       unique: true,
                        validate: {
                            len: [1, 250]
                        }
                    }
                ),
                queryInterface.changeColumn(
                  'subject_tags',
                  'tag_description',
                    {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING,
                        allowNull: false,
                        validate: {
                            len: [1, 250]
                        }
                    }
                ),
                queryInterface.changeColumn(
                  'subject_tags',
                  'associated_subject',
                    {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING,
                        allowNull: false,
                        validate: {
                            len: [1, 250]
                        }
                    }
                )
        ];
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {

  }
};
```

Is any one know why I am encountering this issue?

Comment: have to tried manual query to check if the table really exsist

Comment: @KevalGohil : table exist in sqlite table in database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing lot of googling, I found the answer in the github [discussion](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/133)

Quoting sdepold

> Hey guys. The migration functions are supposed to return promises. So
>   if you want to do multiple things in a migration, just return a
>   chained promised like this:

```
return queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'email').then(function () {
  return queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'encryptedPassword');
});
```

hence the correct code

```
module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.changeColumn(
                  'subject_tags',
                  'tag',
                    {
                       type: Sequelize.STRING,
                       unique: true,
                        validate: {
                            len: [1, 250]
                        }
                    }
                ). then( function () {

                   return queryInterface.changeColumn(
                    #.......
                    );
                }).then( function () {
                    return queryInterface.changeColumn(
                    #.......
                    );
                }) ;
```

Hope this answer the question .